# adding values to variable array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, dynamic

I am trying to loop through a `table` that has a `column` for `"customers" and "dollar amount"`. If my loop finds a `customer` called `"greg" or "henry"` I want to add his `"dollar amount"` to an array of an unknown size.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If by unknown size, you mean that number of elements is unknown, you could use a dynamic array.

```
Dim aArray() As Single ' or whatever data type you wish to use
ReDim aArray(1 To 1) As Single
If strFirstName = "henry" Then
    aArray(UBound(aArray)) = 123.45
    ReDim Preserve aArray(1 To UBound(aArray) + 1) As Single
End If
```

Ubound(aArray) throws an error if the array hasn't been dimensioned, so we start by adding an element to it.  That leaves us with an empty element at the end of the text, so your code should account for that.  aArray(Ubound(aArray)-1) will give you the last valid element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ArrayMy(DataRange)
  Dim DataIndex() As String
  i = 0
  On Error Resume Next
  ReDim DataIndex(0)
  For Each c In DataRange
      DataIndex(i) = c
      i = i + 1
      ReDim Preserve DataIndex(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to use the listArray object:

```
Dim list, name as variant
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

For i = 1 to Last then  ''Loop in the range
    If strName = "Henry" then
        list.Add ValueToAdd  ''add to the list
    End if 
Next
```

and then you can loop in the list

```
For Each name in List
    Msgbox name
Next
```

Comment: Late to the party here, but have you actually tried to run this code? In a VBA environment? There are quite a few errors that prevent it from even compiling.